# Skew-symmetric bilinear form on a vector subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V$ is a $m$-dimensional vector space and $W$ is an even $n$-
 dimensional subspace.

Suppose we have a skew-symmetric bilinear form $B[x, y] = \sum_{k=1}^n x_{k}y_{n+k}-x_{n+1}y_k$ on $W$.

I am interested in the dimension of the space of automorphisms $\phi: V \to V$ such that $ \phi \vert_W$ has the property that $B[\phi_W (x), \phi_W (y)] = B[x,y]$, i.e it preserves the bilinear form on $W$.

I am not sure that such a problem has an easy answer and am only looking for an idea as to how to start thinking about this.